# Why nested dictionary slows down numpy save?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose we have the following code

```
import numpy as np

D = []
for _ in range(200):
   d = []
   for _ in range(300):
      d.append({'a': np.random.randn(64, 64, 3), 'b': np.random.randn(64, 64, 3)})
   D.append(d)

np.save('data', D)
```

It takes really long time to save this data. Is there something wrong with the code, or is it because of dictionary object ?

**-----------------------Update----------------------------**

By taking the dictionary outside, even though with same data size, it is dramatically faster. So it seems it is the dictionary which slows down the process. Is there some potential reason for that ?

i.e.

```
import numpy as np

D1 = []
D2 = []
for _ in range(200):
   d1 = []
   d2 = []
   for _ in range(300):
      d1.append(np.random.randn(64, 64, 3))
      d2.append(np.random.randn(64, 64, 3))
   D1.append(d1)
   D2.append(d2)

np.save('d1', D1)
np.save('d2', D2)
```

Comment: a float is 4 bytes. So 64 * 64 * 3 * 2 * 300 * 200 / 4 / 1024 / 1024 = more than 350 megs of data. Plus, by the end of your for loops, python has to count though almost 60.000 indices before it can append. So no, this isn't weird. Especially if you're on a 5400 rpm hard disk.

Comment: `save` uses `pickle` to write the non array parts. `save` is fastest for a simple multidimensional array.  Even then a very large one will take time.

Comment: Firstly, you are trying to produce 5 to 10 GB of data (depending whether you use 32 or 64 bit numbers), plus overhead of data structures, which takes quite some time only to generate and even longer to save. Secondly, you are trying to save a list of lists of dictionaries of arrays, which is not a natural NumPy data type, so it takes a long time to convert it to an array first before saving it too. You'd probably be better off saving to arrays, `a` and `b`, each with size `(200, 300, 64, 64, 3)`, and slice later as needed.

Comment: @Loek Another phenomenon is that by taking the dictionary outside, even though with same data size, it is dramatically faster. So it seems it is the dictionary which slows down the process. Is there some potential reason for that ?

Comment: Oof, I really don't know enough Python implementation details to answer that. Maybe someone else can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which does something similar but in an efficient, vectorized way, without slow `for` loops:

```
np.savez('data',
    a=np.random.randn(200, 300, 64, 64, 3),
    b=np.random.randn(200, 300, 64, 64, 3))
```

The output format is a little different--it's more compact and will be more efficient to read back.

Note that is almost 12 GB of data, so of course it will take a while to generate the random numbers and write them to disk.  If your real data is lower entropy than random numbers, you may consider using `savez_compressed()` to enable compression and save some disk space (at the cost of CPU time when saving and loading).